# Get the column count in MySQL 3.23

Tags: mysql

I am working with MySQL 3.23 and I want a query that returns the number of columns in a table. I tried the following query but I got the error shown below.

---

#### Attempted query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'tbl_ifo'
```

---

#### Error:

[image]

---

#### Update 1:

After doing some research, I found out that information_schema is only found in MySQL version 5.0 and above. Does anyone know a different way to get the column count?

Comment: MySQL 3.23 production release was 22 January 2001, and MySQL 5.0 in October 2005 - you are 15 years late to upgrade to something newer

Comment: What context are you running your query in?  If it is in php, then you can fetch one row and then count the elements retrieved by the query.  Sorry, I'm not aware if this can be done within MySQL's scripting language.

Good luck.

Comment: You can brute force with something like `select * from tbl_ifo order by 1 limit 1`. Increase the number in `order by` until the query fails ;-)

Comment: @mvp I said the same thing to my mentor XD. The database is like a dinosaur from the Jurassic era.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use see manual for miore descrition

```
SHOW [FULL] COLUMNS {FROM | IN} tbl_name [{FROM | IN} db_name] [LIKE 'pattern']
```

Then you count the number of results.

Such thing as Informationschema was not available at that time.

also your programming language should give back the affected rows.

Comment: How do I store the result of this query in a variable so I can use `Select Count(*)`? Or is there a different way to count the rows?

Comment: for this version doesn't exist a count, only your progrtamming language has some sort  of giving you a count of affected rows, so check a search engine with the termms for example php affected rows